# Proof of "closed-formula solutions" of $AX=0$, with $A$ matrix $ n \times n $ of rank $n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider $$AX=0,$$ homogeneous linear system, with $A$ matrix $ n \times n $ of rank $n-1$.

> How do I prove that the non-trivial solutions of
>   such system is an $n$-tuple that is proportional to the $n$-tuple of the [minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of order
>   $n-1$ obtained by cancelling the first, second, etc. columns?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let, $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 &\dots &a_n\end{bmatrix}, \text{ where } a_i \in \mathbb{F}^n \ \forall \ i=1,2,\dots,n.$
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{F}^n.
$$
$$
Ax = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i
$$

Because the rank of $A$ is $(n-1)$, so with out loss of generality we can consider that $a_j$ is the dependent column. This implies that $\sum_{\substack{i=0 \\ i\neq j}}^{n}\alpha_ia_i+\alpha_ja_j=\theta_n \ (\alpha_j \neq 0)$.

$$a_j = \alpha_j^{-1}\big(\sum_{\substack{i=0 \\ i\neq j}}^{n}\alpha_ia_i\big).$$

$$\sum_{\substack{i=0 \\ i\neq j}}^{n}\alpha_ia_i = \theta_n$$
only when all the $\alpha_i = 0$.